# I can't access to details of my 'products' app

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have two apps on my Django project : `products` and `blog`. 
Everything else works correctly but in my list of the products : `/products/` where the titles of the products are in, when I click on the title I stay on the same page: `/products` . But when I go directly to  `products/1` or `products/2` it works .

**product_list.html :**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

{% for instance in object_list %}
<p>{{ instance.id }} -  <a href="{{ instance.get_absolute_url }}"> {{ 
instance.title }}</a> </p>

{% endfor %}
{% endblock  %}
```

**models.py :**

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class Product(models.Model) :
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=130)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    price       = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=2)
    summary     = models.TextField()
    Featured    = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    def get_absolute_url(self,id):
       return  reverse("products : product_detail",kwargs={"id":self.id})
```

**urls :**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from products.views import (
  product_detail_view ,
  product_create_view ,
  product_delete_view ,
  product_list_view ,
  product_update_view ,
)
app_name = 'products'

urlpatterns = [


path('<int:id>/', product_detail_view, name='product_detail'),
path('create/', product_create_view, name='product_create'),
path('<int:id>/delete/', product_delete_view, name='product_delete'),
path('', product_list_view, name='product_list'),
path('<int:id>/update/', product_update_view, name='product_update'),


]
```

**views :**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404 , redirect
from .models import Product
from .forms import ProductForm

def product_detail_view(request,id):
     obj=get_object_or_404(Product,id=id)
     context = {
        'object' : obj
    }
    return render( request , "products/product_detail.html" , context )

def product_create_view(request):
    form=ProductForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        form = ProductForm()
    context = {
        'form' : form
    }
        return render( request , "products/product_create.html" , context )


def product_delete_view(request,id) :
    obj=get_object_or_404(Product,id=id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        obj.delete()
        return redirect("../../")
    context = {
        'object': obj

    }
    return render( request , "products/product_delete.html" , context )

def product_list_view(request):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()   #list of objects
    context = {
    'object_list' : queryset
    }
     return render( request , "products/product_list.html" , context )

def product_update_view(request,id=id):
    obj=get_object_or_404(Product,id=id)
    form = ProductForm(request.POST or None,instance=obj)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, "products/product_create.html", context)
```

Any help ?

Comment: where are those urls of the titles?

Comment: src> blog : { templates > articles > article_create.html and article_detail.html and article_list.html , forms , models , urls , views } , products { templates > products > product_create.html and product_detail.html and product_list.html , forms , models , urls , views }

Comment: in get_absolute_url try running it without passing id as parameter and then tell what problem you are facing

Comment: `get_absolute_url(self,id)` function should be inside the class `Product`, check the indentation.

Comment: Yes it's inside the class Product . and still not working.

Comment: remove id as parameter as @shekhar suggested.

Comment: @LaasriNadia did you try it directly  def get_absolute_url(self) without id

Comment: when i delete id from get_absolute_url(self,id) i got another error which is NoReverseMatch at /products/
'products ' is not a registered namespace

Comment: @LaasriNadia the second issue is actually unrelated, it's just hidden by the first. Now you've corrected the first issue (removing the extraneous 'id' argument from `get_absolute_url()`), the method is correctly invoked, but it has errors too. FWIW, note that you must not add extra whitespaces in namespaced urls.

Comment: In the line `return  reverse("products : product_detail",kwargs={"id":self.id})` try removing the space infront of `product_detail`.

Comment: Thank you guys , it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing `id` parameter for the function `get_absolute_url()` according to @shekhar

In the line,

`return reverse("products : product_detail",kwargs={"id":self.id})`

try removing the space infront of `product_detail`. Space infront of `product_detail` makes it take a `char` infront of the `char p` and makes it a **different** value altogether while taking parameter for the function `reverse`.

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
       return  reverse("products:product_detail",kwargs={"id":self.id})
```